# Secure Pages Best Practice

Tags: plugin-development, pages, shortcode, security

I am in process of writing a plugin that has front-end shortcodes that display a user's information/data.  If the user is not logged in, I need to redirect to a front-end login page/form.  What would be the best practice here?  My plugin creates the pages that I use as well as add the shortcodes to those pages.  So, if there is a way to "protect" those pages I would love to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the best practices, but I have a few custom login-sensitive pages which simply display a message if user is not logged and is trying to view the page directly:

```
$logged_in = is_user_logged_in();

if($logged_in) {
?>
<article id="post">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
</article>
<?php
} else {
    _e('You are not logged in. Please ', 'abc');
    echo '<a href="' . site_url( 'login' ) . '">'. __('log in','abc') .'</a> ' . __('or','abc') . ' ';
    echo '<a href="' . site_url( 'register' ) . '">'. __('register','abc') .'</a>.';
}
```

Note: both the `login` and `register` pages are custom pages as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is there a way to redirect the user to my front-end login page without getting the "Warning Headers Already Sent" message?

Comment: Hm. By the looks of it [this snippet](http://madebyraygun.com/blog/2012/wordpress-snippet-redirect-all-non-logged-in-users-to-login-page/) should work. If you want conditions then a plugin could be the way to go, such as [this one](http://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't [redirect users from a shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99268/21376). Shortcodes run too late-- well after content has been sent. But given that your plugin is creating the *Pages* you should be able to do this:

```
function protect_plugin_page_wpse_101230() {
  if(is_page('page-slug') && !is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_safe_redirect('your-login-page-url');
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect','protect_plugin_page_wpse_101230');
```